# Is it possible to remove every occurance of a character and one character after it from entire string using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to remove every occurance of a character + one after it from entire string?

Here's a code that achieves what I described, but is rather big:

```
private static string FilterText(string text){
string filteredText = text;

while (true)
{
    int comaIndex = filteredText.IndexOf('.');

    if (comaIndex == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (comaIndex > 1)
    {
        filteredText = filteredText.Substring(0, comaIndex) + filteredText.Substring(comaIndex + 2);
    }
    else if (comaIndex == 1)
    {
        filteredText = filteredText[0] + filteredText.Substring(comaIndex + 2);
    }
    else
    {
        filteredText = filteredText.Substring(comaIndex + 2);
    }
}

return filteredText;
}
```

This code would turn for example input `.Otest.1 .2.,string.w..` to `test string`

Is it possible to achieve the same result using regex?

Comment: Do you require regex, or just something that can parse gigantic strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use

```cs
var output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\..", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C..&i=.Otest.1%20.2.%2Cstring.w..&r=&o=s). *Details*:

- `\.` - matches a dot
- `.` - matches any char including a line feed char due to the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option used.

Comment: Doesn't look like the trailing character should be optional, the dot at the end of the string is deleted not because it is a dot but because it follows a dot.

Comment: The first code snippet matches what I was looking for.

Comment: @herosnowman Ok, I removed another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?<!\.)\w+`

code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test{
    public static void Main(){
        string str = ".Otest.1 .2.,string.w..";
        Console.WriteLine(FilterText(str));

    }
    private static string FilterText(string text){
        string pattern = @"(?<!\.)\w+";  
        string result = "";
        foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(text, pattern)){
            result += m + " ";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

output:

```
test string
```